# Why my Ubuntu online account become black in the last step?

Tags: unity, google, online-accounts

Every time I grant Ubuntu 16.04 to access Google account in Online Accounts last step the next screen become black. After I check I still not logged yet.

- Last click before blank:

  [image: Last click before blank]
- Black blank screen:

  [image: Black blank screen]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But this looks to be a known bug. It was fixed and they are rolling the updates. You should receive on the next few days.

If you want it a little faster go to "software and updates" and change your mirror to use ubuntu's main mirror.

[BUG at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019)